# Changing a list of tensors to a tensor of lists!

Tags: python, tensorflow, numpy

I have a list of tensors created by

```
[some_function(x) for x in something]
```

and this list becomes like this

```
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'I have gone and you will go'>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'we will go'>]
```

But I want to have an object like this

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=string, numpy=array([b'I have gone and you will go', b'we will go'], dtype=object)>
```

Which is a tensor of list of strings (Opposite to the previous one). Is there any way to this, assuming that I have access to all these tensors, i.e. `some_function(x) for x in something` separately.

Answer (score 1):

In order to stack list of tf tensors you could use the tf function `stack` hence the name

for ur case,

```py
tf.stack([some_function(x) for x in something],axis=0)
```

or you could stack them in numpy and then convert the array to a tensor, to do so using numpy `np.stack` inputting a list and axis